# Cell fill colour optionally not to print

Tags: excel

I have a protected worksheet and keeping few cells are editable to user.

Which is filled with a green colour to indicate the user can edit the cell.

But at same time I want to print these cells without the background colour.

If I choose the option in page setup `'Print : Black/White'`
, other cells, which i want to preserve the colour fill for, are also cleared e.g.
the top row (heading) is filled with a grey colour and the Total has a dark grey colour.

Comment: How about using conditional formatting? If cell is blank or equal to specific value, fill with green.Else no fill?

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Formatting would be your best bet.

Otherwise I would use VBA to do this. I've done this by creating a print button and assigning it to a print macro.

The macro would consist of two functions:

1. `Range(xxx).Interior.Color = xlNone`
2. `ActiveSheet.PrintPreview`